# Three.js Plane and line intersectLine

Tags: three.js, line, intersect, plane

I have a problem about how `.intersectLine` works in **three.js**

I have a line (line)  and a plane (planoref) , and I want to know the point of intersection.

```
new THREE.Vector3( planoref.intersectLine(line));
```

but the response was: `planoref.intersectLine is not a function"`

How does this function work?
How can I know the point of intersection of a line or ray with a plane?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably contains an error, or perhaps you are using an outdated version of three.js. The following code fragment works and outputs the expected "5".

```
var line = new THREE.Line3(new THREE.Vector3(0,10,0), new THREE.Vector3(0,-10,0));
var planoref = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -5);
alert( planoref.intersectLine(line).y);
```